# Trying to find a sequence of continuous functions that are bounded and decreasing on $[0,1]$ with no limit that has continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to find a sequence of functions which are continuous on $[0,1]$ which are uniformly bounded, decreasing (monotone), and where the limit is not continuous.

I have proposed the series of functions $f_n(x) = 1-x^n$. Would this satisfy the above? I have proved boundedness, non continuous limit, but havent been able to show the monotone decreasing part. Is it done by induction? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence of decreasing functions or for a decreasing sequence or both? Oh, and the sequence you are proposing is an increasing sequence of decreasing functions...

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are trying to do, but if you want to show that each $f_n$ is monotone decreasing, just show that if $a>b$ then $f_n(a)<f_n(b)$, which is quite easy to do with these functions.